# rdoc file how include content from local txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rdoc

I have a readme file in rails project and rake task which generate text file.

I want include content from this file to my Readme.rdoc is it possible
Everything I get after googling - some :include: directive
I include it to my Readme.rdoc:

```
 == Some title
   :include: rubocop.txt
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the file `rubycop.txt` is in the current directory, the directory containing it should be listed using `--include` option.

Comment: txt file in the same directory. but I don't use any generators to build readme - it is static

Comment: @Vladimir, the same directory does not mean the working directory.

Comment: readme placed within project root directory. txt file also there